# Adding subdomain in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, routes, subdomain, inertiajs

For some reason adding subdomain route isn't working and keeps on returning my homepage instead of the page I need. I'm using Laravel, Inertiajs Vue in my app.

Here is my route:

```php
Route::domain('webshopview.localhost:8000')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/webshopview', function () {
        return Inertia::render('Products/Index');
    });
});
```

I want to be able to access it as webshopview.localhost:8000 but every time I try to visit this route it returns my app home page. If I do this in normal route like the below example, it works like a charm.

```php
Route::get('/webshopview', function () {
    return Inertia::render('Products/Index');
});
```

What is missing to create a subdomain for group of routes? Why it keeps returning the app homepage ignoring the subdomain

My app works locally on 'http://localhost:8000/' and 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' and it works like that by default without me doing anything. So all I want is to add subdomain to specific routes so that I can access like this 'example.localhost:8000' or 'example.127.0.0.1:8000'. The end result is to have the route displayed like this after deployment 'https://www.subdomain.domain.com'

I even tried this and it didn't work:

```php
Route::get('/productview', function () {
    return 'First sub domain';
})->domain('productview.localhost');
```

now accessing 'http://productview.localhost/' returns 'This site can’t be reached' error.

Comment: You mean your webserver is configured to listen both to the normal HTTP (or HTTPS) port and port 8000 and directs both these ports to your Laravel app?

Comment: @apokryfos My app works locally on 'http://localhost:8000/' and 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/' and it works like that by default without me doing anything. So all I want is to add subdomain to specific routes so that I can access like this 'example.localhost:8000' or 'example.127.0.0.1:8000'. The end result is to have the route displayed like this after deployment 'https://www.subdomain.domain.com'

Comment: Don't include the port at all. It should default to whatever port your app is on if you don't include it

Comment: You mean like this? 'http://productview.localhost/' ? If that's what you mean, it doesn't work

Comment: @apokryfos Is there any changes I should do on windows to make this work locally?

Comment: you'd need to add something like `127.0.0.1 productview.localhost` in your `C:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file (can only edit as admin)

Comment: Apparently using `<anything>.localtest.me` should work instead of using locahost as well with no additional setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually add the routes in my etc/hosts file on windows and restart the entire machine for it to take effect.